# Import Excel-file and then edit

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

Good afternoon. Such a question. Want to import Excel-file with the table, followed by editing or saving to the database. Get in the controller **"import"** empty.

```
array(1) { ["document"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Just does not work validation.

Model file

```
class DocumentForm extends CFormModel {
public $document;
public function rules() {
return array(
    array('document', 'required'),
    array('document','file','types'=>'xls,xlsx'),
);
}

public function attributeLabels() {
return array(
    'document' => 'Документ',
);
}
}
```

The controller (index)

```
$docModel=new DocumentForm;$this->render('index',array('docModel'=>$docModel));
```

Representation (index)

```
echo CHtml::form('','POST',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
echo CHtml::activeFileField($docModel, 'document');
echo CHtml::button('Импорт', array('submit' => array('import')));
echo CHtml::endForm();
```

View to edit the table (import)

```
if(isset($_POST['DocumentForm'])) {
$docModel->attributes = $_POST['DocumentForm'];
$docModel->document = CUploadedFile::getInstance($docModel,'document');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($documentModel->document->tempName);
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['DocumentForm']['tmp_name']['document']); 
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but the validation does not work.